# Fail to verify bitcode in TwitterKit.framwork/TwitterKit error: Platform iOS is not supported

Tags: ios, ipa, bitcode

I'm facing error while generating ipa, I was recently updating all pod plugins. After that I got this error, please check with the attached image:

[image: Please check image for understanding issue]

Answer (score 3):

Go to your Project --> Target --> Build Settings --> Set NO to Enable Bitcode

And then retry to build.

For iOS apps, bitcode is optional. For wastchOS bitcode enabled is required.

If you provide bitcode, all apps and frameworks in the app bundle need to include bitcode.

Bitcode is automatically turned Yes from Xcode 7. 
So,either you should get an updated framework from the vendor with bitcode enabled or you should turn bitcode to NO. There is some information regarding this [here](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitterkit-was-built-without-full-bitcode/95009) for the version to be used for the Twitter framework with bitcode enabled.